# Use keyboard arrows to move to next textformfield

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, keyboard

I have created a contact form with a few textformfields. When I'm using the keyboard I want to also use the the arrows at the top of the keyboard to move to next textformfield. I have already implemented TextInputAction.next so that when clicking on "return" you go to next textformfield, but I also want to include the arrows to do the same to go up/down.

The image below shows the arrows I want to include action on.

[image: Current keyboard status]

This is my current textformfield code:

```
Widget _createTextField(controller, keyboardType, int maxLength, int maxLines, String hintText, double screenWidth) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: (screenWidth > maxMobileScreenWidth) ? 16 : 12),
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        maxLength: maxLength,
        maxLines: maxLines,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value!.isEmpty) {
            return '* Required field';
          }
          return null;
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          counterText: "",
          filled: true,
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          fillColor: const Color(0xff9ccb40),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use the `Form()` widget, on top of all your TextFromField.
you can use `Form(child:Column(children:[])`
[suggest you to read this article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

Comment: I should have posted more of my code, sorry. I'm already using Form with a formkey on top of all my TextFormField. Comparing it to the article, I have implemented it correctly also. Any other ideas?